# Проблема с деструктором при использовании конструктора копирования?

Tags: c++

Всем, добрый день! Возник следующий вопрос при изучении с++:

имеется класс Sea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

class Sea {
private:
    char* sea_name;
    int max_depth;
    double square;

public:
    void SetSeaName(const char* p) {
        if (strlen(p) != strlen(this->sea_name) || this->sea_name == nullptr) {
            delete[] this->sea_name;
            this->sea_name = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
        }
        strcpy(this->sea_name, p);
    }

    Sea(const char* arr, int d, double s) : max_depth(d), square(s) {
        this->sea_name = new char[strlen(arr) + 1];
        strcpy(this->sea_name, arr);
    }

    Sea(int d, double s) : Sea("cde", d, s) {
    }

    ~Sea() {
        delete[] sea_name;
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
    }

    Sea() {
        this->sea_name = new char[4];
        strcpy(this->sea_name, "abc");
        this->max_depth = 1000;
        this->square = 100000;
    }

    //Конструктор копирования
    Sea(const Sea& param) : sea_name(param.sea_name), max_depth(param.max_depth), square(param.square) {
        cout << "Copy Constructor is worked!" << endl;
    }

};
```

Он содержит в себе несколько конструкторов, в том числе и конструктор копирования.

В main создаю несколько экземпляров класса:

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);

    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    {
        Sea s1();
        Sea s2("aaaa", 1000, 2000.5);
        Sea s3(1000, 200.5);
        Sea s4 = s3;
        Sea s5(100, 100);

    }

    Sea* s4 = new Sea();
    s4->~Sea();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема возникает вот здесь: `Sea s4=s3;` - при вызове деструктора s4. Не могу понять, в чём проблема (Вернее догадываюсь, что проблема в том, что у `s3` - деструктор - вызывается дважды, но не знаю как этого избежать - т.к здесь он так же вызовется 
`Sea s3(1000, 200.5);`).

Сколько смотрел примеров на просторах интернета - во всех, примерно так же и никаких проблем не возникает.

Comment: Эм, так проблема в том, что вызывается 2 деструктор у `s4` и `s3`? Я не понял. Предоставьте лучше вывод программы.

Comment: проблема в том, что когда вызывается конструктор s4 - программа вываливается с ошибкой

Comment: @Harry предоставил ответ.

Comment: Я уже писал вам в предыдущем вопросе: для вашего класса не выполняется Правило Трех.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конструкторе копирования вам надо поступить так же, как и в обычном - **выделить** память для строки `sea_name`, а не копировать указатель.